# How can I handle change in multiple input field and send the data to an api with axios?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object-destructuring

I'm trying to handle change in multiple input text field and send the value to an API
Here is what i have tried

```
const [state, setState] = useState({
    Value_A:'', 
    Value_B:'', 
    Value_c:'', 
    Value_D:'', 
    Value_e:''})
```

The handleChange function right here

```
function handleChange(evt) {
    const value = evt.target.value;
    setState({
        ...state,
        [evt.target.name]:value
    })
}
```

So how can I do to get those values inside the function handleSubmit()

```
const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    const a = {
    // How to get those values here?
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The concept you are trying here is known as `Controlled Component` in reactjs, on every change of input we update the associated state and on form submit we get the updated state. In your case you will get it like:

```
const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    let formValues = {...state};  // spread operator is used to clone the data
    // Your API call goes here
}
```

[Controlled Component Reference](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components)

Comment: Solved my problem. Thank you!

Comment: @AndrainionyFenohasina happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    const a = {...state};
    // Your API call goes here
}
```